# ImportJSON no incluye objetos "null"

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

**[Pregunta original acá]**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862819/importjson-doesnt-include-nulls

He estado usando este script hecho por Brad Jasper and Trevor Lohrbeer para importar datos JSON a Google Sheets. Utilizo la función personalizada (formula) `ImportJSON` solamente porque a la versión advanced no entiendo bien cuales son los argumentos que debo entregarle para obtener resultados. La función la llamo desde Google Sheets y es la siguiente

`=ImportJSON("https://api.keepa.com/product?key=ACÁ VA LA API KEY&domain=1&asin="&$B$1&"&rental=0&fbafees=0&rating=0&history=1&stats=0","/products/csv","noTruncate,allHeaders")`

siendo `$B$1` un código de identificación de artículos en Amazon, por ejemplo `0415933234`.

**VER SCRIPT ACÁ**
https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs

Estoy tratando de analizar datos desde keepa.com (maneja información de precios histórica de Amazon).

En la respuesta al importar los datos Json, el objeto en "/product/csv" contiene 32 objetos anidados o "ramas" con datos de diversas categorías correspondiente cada rama a un tipo de información específica, cuando esta información no existe, se entrega el valor "null" (ver imagen 1)

[image: El arbol a la izquierda es del objeto csv con 32 ramas de 0 a 31]

Cuando importo los datos Json a google sheets, el script elimina los valores "null, entregando sólo las ramas con datos en ellas (0 a 5,11,12,14 y 30 en este caso), lo cual arruina mi array.

Traté usando la opción "noInherit" sin éxito (ver imagen 2):

[image: !(https://i.imgur.com/LRJkwFs.jpg)]

[El API de Keepa, busquen el objeto CSV] https://keepa.com/#!discuss/t/product-object/116

Quiero que se muestren las ramas aunque contengan "null" en ellas, hay alguna forma de que fuese posible? (ver ejemplo en imagen 3)

Gracias!

[image: Asi me gustaría que quedara]

Comment: Bienvenido. La pregunta es demasiado amplia ya que incluyes varias preguntas en un publicación pero sólo se debería incluir una. Sobre el código que has modificado deberías señalar de alguna forma los cambios que realizaste pues aquí considerando a los que tienen ánimo de responder pero no son expertos en IMPORTJSON. Por cierto, ¿preguntaste lo mismo en el sitio en inglés? Si fuera así, no hay ningún problema pero sería bueno que incluyeras un enlace a dicha pregunta particularmente si tu eres el autor de la misma.

Comment: Gracias Rubén, si también hice la pregunta en el sitio en inglés, este es el el enlace a la pregunta en inglés:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862819/importjson-doesnt-include-nulls-and-how-to-split-or-truncate-over-50000-charac]
Escencialmente son dos cosas, necesito importar las 32 ramas que componen el objeto CSV (aunque su valor sea null) y si una rama es demasiado larga (el límite de google sheets por celda es de 50000 caracteres) mover el texto restante a la siguiente columna. Gracias!

Comment: Cada cosa debe preguntarse por separado (publica cada una en preguntas distintas)

Comment: ok, lo haré, gracias!

Comment: La pregunta ahora es más específica así que ha mejorado, sin embargo, aún le falta para hacerla suficientemente específica para ser respondida en este sitio, por ejemplo no mencionas cual de las funciones estás usando ni si la estás usando en una fórmula, si la ejecutas desde el editor de Apps Script. Lo primero que debes hacer es estudiar el código del proyecto en GitHub y entender las diferentes funciones principales. Quizás las que te sea más útil es `ImportJSONAdvanced`. Si te decides por esta, incluye una breve descripción de cómo has intentado usarla y dónde te has quedado atorado.

Comment: Gracias Rubén, soy diseñador gráfico, no programador, algo de código entiendo pero lo básico, utilizo la función ImportJSON solamente porque a la versión advanced no entiendo bien cuales son los argumentos que debo entregarle para obtener resultados.

la función la llamo desde google sheets y es la siguiente ```=ImportJSON("https://api.keepa.com/product?key=ACÁ VA LA API KEY&domain=1&asin="&$B$1&"&rental=0&fbafees=0&rating=0&history=1&stats=0","/products/csv","noTruncate,allHeaders")``` siendo "&$B$1&" un código de identificación de artículos en amazon, por ejemplo 0415933234.

Comment: No te preocupes, aquí son bienvenidas las preguntas de todos, no importa profesión, estudios, origen, de todas formas  las reglas del sitio son las mismas para todos. Mientras mejor sea tu pregunta mayores probabilidades tendrás de tener una buena respuesta.

Comment: En cuanto a la formula, así como cualquier otro dato relevante para poder responder la pregunta adecuadamente debe ir en la pregunta misma, no en los comentarios pues se pretende que estos sean temporales además de que si existen muchos comentarios, se podrían ocultar e incluso eliminar si la varios usuarios votan para que ello ocurra.

Answer (score 0):

En la parte del código que recorre cada una de las ramas principales deberías poner una condición de si la rama tiene `null` (no me queda claro si te lo pasa como cadena o como objeto) devuelva un Array del tamaño apropiado con el valor por defecto que quieras usar el cual podría ser una cadena vacía `''`, pero no un elemento vacío.

Answer (score 0):

NOTA: Este respuesta es considerando la información adicional inicialmente proporcionada por el AP a través de comentarios a la pregunta.

La función personalizada IMPORTJSON del proyecto que refieres tiene un alcance limitado es por ello que los autores del proyecto han incluido la función `ImportJSONAdvanced` la cual incluye los argumentos

- url
- fetchOptions
- query
- parseOptions
- includeFunc
- transformFunc

Usa `includeFunc` y `transformFunc` para pasar funciones para determinar que es lo que que se debe incluir en la importación y cómo transformar los datos luego de que ha sido importado.

`includeFunc` debe ser una función con el patrón `func(query, path, options)`  que devuelva verdero si el elemento de datos in una ruta determinada debe ser incluído o falso en caso contrario.

`transformFunc` debe ser una función con el patrón `func(data, row, column, options)` donde data es un objeto de tipo Array de dos dimensiones (2D) de los datos y row y column son la fila y columnas que actualmente están siendo procesadas. Cualquier valor "return" es ignorado.

NOTA: `ImportJSONAdvanced` no puede usarse como función personalizada ya que no es posible pasar como funciones JavaScript como argumentos en formulas de hoja de cálculo de Google.

Si todo esto te resulta demasiado complicado, tal vez deberías considerar crear tu propia función IMPORTJSON y aprender lo necesario para poder hacerlo.